# How to access AngularJS service/factory in CKEditor custom plugin

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using CKEditor 4 in an AngularJS app.  I have a directive for CKEditor which sets the editor options

```
angular.module('someMod', []).directive("ckeditor", CKEditor).factory('someFactory',someFactory);
...etc...
CKEditor.$inject = ["someFactory"];
function CKEditor(someFactory) {
...and in the link function the editor options includes...
extraPlugins: 'myplugin'
```

Now if I put the custom plugin definition into the link function it works fine because it can reference someFactory no problem.  But I want to put all the "myplugin" code into a separate plugin file.  And this works fine except when it tries to reference someFactory it fails.

Edit ------
The factory is constructed as follows

```
someFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$log', ...];
function someFactory($http, $log, ...) {
    return {
        someFunction: someFunction,
        ...
    };
    function someFunction() {
        // do some stuff
        return 1;
    }
```

Anyone know how to make someFactory available to the CKEditor plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this.  I declare a global variable like

```
var angularObject = {};
```

Then in the CKEditor directive link function I add

```
angularObject = someFactory
```

to create a reference to the factory that was injected into the directive.  Then in the plugin code I can say something like

```
angularObject.someFunction
```

Answer (score 0):

A factory must return an object. If it has not been setup properly that could cause the issue you are experiencing. Would require a more complete example to troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi Mark.  The factory works fine otherwise.  I have updated my question with the factory code